# correct image is not loading in dialog using glide library inside listview

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, android-glide

There is a listview which displays image and text. The image and text are properly displaying in the listview. But when clicking on the image it should display in the dialog in full-screen mode. The image is displayed in dialog but the wrong image is displaying. Whenever an image is clicked in listview it always displays the wrong image (image from the bottom of the list). Below i provided the adapter which I used.

```
  public class DescAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private final listdisplay ds;
    private ArrayList<descusers> dusers;
    private ArrayList<descusers> orig;
    private Activity listdisplay;
    PhotoViewAttacher p;
    String Limage,profile;



    public DescAdapter(listdisplay ds, ArrayList<descusers> dusers,Activity listdisplay) {
        this.ds = ds;
        this.dusers = dusers;
        this.listdisplay = listdisplay;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dusers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dusers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        descusers du = dusers.get(position);
        String username = du.loginname;
        String descCrip=du.descCrip;
        Limage = du.image;
        long Ptime = du.Ptime;
        profile = du.profile;
        Viewholder viewholder = null;
        if(convertView==null) {
            viewholder = new Viewholder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ds).inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
            viewholder.uname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            viewholder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewholder.time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            viewholder.iview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);
            viewholder.civ = (CircleImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            viewholder.progress = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

            Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(profile).centerCrop().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(viewholder.civ);
          convertView.setTag(viewholder);
        }else {

            viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        viewholder.uname.setText(username);
        viewholder.desc.setText(descCrip);

        if (!Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(Limage).matches()) {
            viewholder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            final Viewholder finalViewholder1 = viewholder;
            Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage).centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                           @Override
                           public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                               return false;
                           }

                           @Override
                           public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                           finalViewholder1.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               return false;
                           }
                       }).into(viewholder.iview);
            viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



        final View finalConvertView = convertView;

        viewholder.iview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog builder = new Dialog(listdisplay, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                        new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
                 builder.setContentView(R.layout.imager);

                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        //nothing;
                    }
                });


              ImageView image = (ImageView) builder.findViewById(R.id.image);
                Glide.with(finalConvertView.getContext()).load(Limage)
                         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(image);

              builder.show();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
```

for example:

### if listview displays 3 images:

Text1

### image1

Text2

### image2

Text3

### image3

if I click on image3, it is properly displayed in dialog properly. if I click on image2 then the image3 is displayed not image2. Then image1 is clicked then image2 is displayed in the dialog. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In bindView calls, you must clear() any Views or Targets you might have previously started loads into if you do not start new loads into them. You have two cases above where you are not doing this. The first is here:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    ...
} else {
    // Clear or reload viewholder.civ
}
```

The second is here:

```
if (!Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(Limage).matches()) {
    // Clear or reload viewholder.iview
} else {
    ...
}
```